# foreach MySQL for a list of specific numbers

Tags: mysql, loops, for-loop, select, foreach

I would like to write a foreach loop in mysql. Here the semi-code:

```
numbers = {1,5,3,7,10};
for(number:numbers)
SET @numbers_status := (select * from status where numberId = $number)
// update a table using @numbers_status and $number
```

Comment: Mysql does not have such a construct - perhaps if you explained what you are trying to do someone may be able to help you.

Comment: You're overwriting the `@numbers_status` variable each time through the loop. At the end it will just be the value from the last number, so what's the point of looping?

Comment: Looks like you simply want/need `select * from status where numberId IN(1,5,3,7,10)`

Comment: If you're writing a stored procedure, you can use a query like that and then loop over the results with a cursor.

Comment: And what does it mean to set a variable to the result of `SELECT *`? A variable can only hold one value, not a whole table row.

Comment: I updated the post to make it more clear.

Comment: 'I updated the post to make it more clear' - it doesn't. You could improve this question by adding sample data and expected outcome as text.